# define a variable using tikz calc

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\def\radius{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red] (0, 0) circle [radius=\radius];
  \draw[blue] (0, 0) circle [radius={\radius-1}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to replace `{\radius-1}` with a variable (e.g. `\smallradius`) whose value is computed using `tikz calc`. How could I do that?

Answer (score 6):

No `calc` library needed, just use

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\smallradius{\radius-1}
\draw[blue] (0, 0) circle [radius=\smallradius];
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\radius{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red] (0, 0) circle [radius=\radius];
  \pgfmathsetmacro\smallradius{\radius-1}
  \draw[blue] (0, 0) circle [radius=\smallradius];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My question is about replacing `\radius-1` with a new variable.

Comment: @Viesturs Ok, I reverted to my original answer, which introduced a separate variable. A few minutes after my original answer, I had forgotten about your request regarding the variable, and thought that I could simplify my answer

Answer (score 5):

We can use `\usetikzlibrary{math}`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\tikzmath{
   \radius=2;
   \smallradius=\radius-1;
   \bigradius=2*\radius;
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \draw[red] (0, 0) circle [radius=\radius];
  \draw[blue] (0, 0) circle [radius=\smallradius];
  \draw[green (0, 0) circle [radius=\bigradius];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]